# Monkey Business c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to teach myself C++ using an old textbook and would appreciate your input. I can find working code for the program online, but I want to make my code work before trying completely different approaches.

I need to write a program that uses a 3x7 two-dimensional array to hold daily food consumption throughout a week by 3 monkeys.

I need to output average total daily food consumption, the least amount of weekly food consumption by any monkey, and the greatest weekly food consumption by any monkey.

Everything works so far, except for my getLeast function, which does what it sounds like - getting the least weekly food consumption among the monkeys. However, it outputs zero, while my getMost function seems to work fine.

Additionally, I welcome any comments that can offer advice on how I can improve or streamline my code. Thanks for reading!

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int numberRows = 3;
const int numberCol = 7;

void getData(int array[][numberCol], int);
double getAverage(int array[][numberCol], int);
int getRowSum(int array[][numberCol], int);
double getAverage(int array[][numberCol], int);
int getLeast(int, int, int);
int getMost(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int monkeys[numberRows][numberCol];
    int monkey1 = 0, monkey2 = 1, monkey3 = 2, monk1Total, monk2Total, monk3Total, largest, smallest;
    getData(monkeys,numberRows);
    monk1Total = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey1);
    monk2Total = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey2);
    monk3Total = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey3);
    smallest = getLeast(monk1Total, monk2Total, monk3Total);
    largest = getMost(monk1Total, monk2Total, monk3Total);
    cout << "The average daily food consumption by the monkeys was " << getAverage(monkeys, numberRows)/3 << "." << endl;
    cout << "The smallest amount of food eaten by one monkey in a week was: " << smallest << "."<<endl;
    cout << "The largest amount of food eaten by one monkey in a week was: " << largest << "."<<endl;

}
void getData(int monkeys[][numberCol],int numberRows)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < numberRows; rows++)
    {
        cout << "Monkey " << (rows + 1) << endl;
        for (int cols = 0; cols < numberCol; cols++)
        {
            cout << " Day " << (cols + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> monkeys[rows][cols];
            while (monkeys[rows][cols] < 0){
                cout << "Cannot accept negative numbers, please try again: ";
                cin >> monkeys[rows][cols];}}
        cout << endl;}}
int getRowSum(int monkeys[][numberCol], int monkeyNum)
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < monkeyNum; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < numberCol;cols++)
            total += monkeys[rows][cols];}
    return total;
}
double getAverage(int monkeys[][numberCol], int numberRows)
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int cols = 0; cols < numberCol; cols++){
        for (int rows = 0; rows < numberRows; rows++)
            total += monkeys[rows][cols];}
    return (total/(numberCol));
}

int getMost(int monkey1, int monkey2, int monkey3){
    int array[3]{monkey1, monkey2, monkey3};
    int max = array[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] > max)
        {
            max = array[count];
        }}
    return max;
}

int getLeast(int monkey1, int monkey2, int monkey3)
{
    int array[3]{monkey1, monkey2, monkey3};
    int min = array[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] < min)
        {
            min = array[count];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: The function itself looks ok...

Comment: That's the perfect starting point to learn about how the debugger works, to step through your program line by line, and watch how the variable values are changing actually. Do it, right now. It's about the time to do so (and much faster providing concise results than asking here).

Comment: _@Meagan Sikorsky_ I have to admit, this textbook might be _too old_. I can't spot any modern c++ technique applied here.

Comment: For program improvement advice: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in `getRowSum` is flawed. Use

```
int getRowSum(int monkeys[][numberCol], int monkeyNum)
{
   int total = 0;

   for (int cols = 0; cols < numberCol;cols++)
      total += monkeys[monkeyNum][cols];

      return total;
}
```

I don't know whether fixing it will fix the other problem.